# google ecommerce tracking addItems

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I am Trying to accomplish ecommerce tracking with pure javascript.

Here is my Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function (){

belegnummer = jQuery("#belegnr").text();
kundennummer = jQuery("#kundennummer").text();
menge = 0;
jQuery(".menge").each(function () {
    menge = menge + parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
})

_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
belegnummer,  // order ID - required
kundennummer,   // affiliation or store name
menge,          // total - required
'',           // tax
'',              // shipping
'',       // city
'',     // state or province
''             // country
]);


jQuery(".singleproduct").each(function () {

total = jQuery(this).find(".menge").text();
muenzid = jQuery(this).find(".muenzid").text();

_gaq.push(['_addItem',
belegnummer,           // order ID - required
muenzid,           // SKU/code - required
'',             // product name
'',             // category or variation
'1',          // unit price - required
total               // quantity - required

]); 
})
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers  



})      </script>
```

The tracking works fine except for the addItem. There is no data sent to google analytics. I have tried all kinds of variations and also checked that the variables are being returned correctly by jquery. There is no Javascript error.

Has anyone accomplished this already?

Comment: This is actually the old way to submit transactions to GA ecommerce. If you're able to see my deleted post I got my code working and posting to GA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the bottom of the script:

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```